# python matplotlib patch plot going wrong

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a rectangle with python. Something is going wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

box=[1,3,5]
box_pos=[0,30,4]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(
    patches.Rectangle(
        (box_pos[0], box_pos[1]),   # (x,y)
        box[0],          # width
        box[1],          # height
    )
)

ax.set_aspect(aspect='equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

Do you have any idea what I could do to fix it?

Comment: "Something is going wrong"? What is "something" here? Please clearly state what problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

when you add `patches` to a matplotlib `Axes`, it does not automatically set the axes limits in the same way other plot types do, so your limits are being set to the default `(0, 1)` in both x and y, and your rectangle is outside those limits.

You have a couple of options:

1. use [`ax.autoscale()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-autoscale) before `plt.show()` to let matplotlib automatically set the axes limits

[image]

2. If you want more control, you can set the axes limits manually, using [`ax.set_xlim()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim) and [`ax.set_ylim()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim) before `plt.show()`, e.g.:

   ```
   ax.set_xlim(-20, 20)
   ax.set_ylim(0, 40)
   ```

[image]